# How to declare a variable to store column data

Tags: postgresql

I need to use a variable in postgresql which can store column data.
I am using this right now:

```
DECLARE 
   var_tmp numeric(1);
SELECT number FROM table_tmp;
```

Now here I have multiple data in the `table_tmp.number` but I am only getting last value of the column in `var_tmp` variable. 
what I want to achieve is to take all data from that column to my variable.
for example if I have 10 rows in `table_tmp.number` then I want to assign all 10 rows to `var_tmp` variable.
Is there a way to do that? Should I declare it some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you have to use Temporary table.

```
  CREATE TEMP TABLE table_tmp(
   var_tmp numeric(1)
);

SELECT number INTO table_tmp FROM orig_table ;


 or


CREATE TEMP TABLE table_tmp AS
SELECT number
FROM orig_table;
```

Answer (score 2):

A variable can only hold a single value. If you need to store multiple values, you need an array:

```
DECLARE 
   var_tmp numeric[];
BEGIN
...
   SELECT array_agg(number) 
      into var_tmp 
   FROM table_tmp;
```